# Accelerating BehaviorSpace runs using speed slider?

Tags: netlogo

My Netlogo 6.0.4 model generates custom output using csv commands I coded myself. I have 192 experiments to run (see image below). They proceed using partial ticks equal to the user-supplied "timestep" size. In order to speed up execution, I de-selected "Update View" and "Update plots and monitors". The BehaviorSpace window also includes a slider currently set to "Normal Speed." Question: Since updates are off, does the speed slider have any effect on computation speed? Based on the user manual, I would think not, but despite de-selecting "Update View" I can still move the slider, which suggests to me that it may still be possible.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The speed slider speeds up models by skipping some view updates. So if you uncheck the "Update view" checkbox, you've already done the maximum, the speed slider will not help further.

It would make sense for the speed slider to be grayed out when "Update view" is checked. Not sure why we never did that. (Never thought of it? Or just never got around to it?)